# visibility between containers built with different docker-compose configuration

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to use the service **api_mysql** in **sass_php**. Containers are built with different docker-compose.yml files and I understand they belong to different network and they can't see betweem them. The following is my current configuration, but then when I want to use the service I get:
"php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve":

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                 DRIVER              SCOPE
bcad56c87a8c        repo1_api           bridge              local
196f42d7cbea        repo2_api           bridge              local
79b41a714b48        repo2_sass          bridge              local
```

docker-compose-1.yml

```
networks:
  api:

services:

  api_mysql:
    ...
    networks:
      api:

  api_php:
    ...
    depends_on:
      - api_mysql
    networks:
      api:
```

docker-compose-2.yml

```
version: '3'

networks:
  api:
  sass:

services:

  sass_mysql:
    ...
    networks:
      sass:

  sass_php:
    ...
    depends_on:
      - sass_mysql
    networks:
      api:
      sass:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As they live in different networks so do their domain names. The DNS used by `sass_php` does not access the domain names available in `repo1_api` network. It can access the ones in `repo2_api` network but this network is not used by `api_mysql`.

So to remediate, you can declare your network outside your `docker-compose` files and add it that way:

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my-pre-existing-network
```

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network

Or you can `EXPOSE` the `api_mysql` ports to your localhost and access by it.

I would prefer the first method.